# Is there a limit to number of shared id's on SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building a SQLite database of Indian language translations that's going to use a bit heavy memory size. It would be useful for a host of news media applications. But if a user has to download 7 or 8 media apps it would be senseless to download the same database several times.

Specifying shared user Id's on xml may be a solution. But is there any better alternative. Because i have no profit motive, my only intention is to see tens of media companies openly utilizing my database. If there's no such Open way of letting developers access database i will try to pre-specify a 200 or more shared id's and allot to interested media companies in future? But is there any limit for such number of id's too on SQLite?

Comment: I'm not understanding the question

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) would be helpful in getting started.